# useSelector doesn't work in react redux app

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, useselector

I am creating a counter application using react and redux.

In the `counterSlice.js` file, I included this line:
`export const selectCount = (state) => state.count;`

And in the `Counter.js` file, I have included these lines:

`import { changeValueBy, selectCount } from "./counterSlice";`

`const count = useSelector(selectCount);`

But the value of `count` remains `undefined`.
My complete code is [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/counter-app-using-react-and-redux-yv8dhy?file=/src/features/counter/Counter.js:264-303).
Please tell me what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed out to create a store and wrap the app with its `Provider` as following:

```
import { Counter } from "./features/counter/Counter";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { createStore } from "redux";
import counter from "./features/counter/counterSlice";

const store = createStore(counter);

function App() {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
       <Counter />
    </Provider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

BTW, I fixed your codesanbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/counter-app-using-react-and-redux-forked-2e14p9?file=/src/features/counter/counterSlice.js)

Comment: But why does the `Provider` in the index.js file not work?

Comment: Which file were you mentioning?

Comment: In the `index.js` file